# how to make a tuple that contains functions

Tags: c++

The problem I have is that I need to store functions (pointers to functions) that receive an object (suppose a Obj) and return bool, all in a unique "entity". I came with the idea of making tuples of functions, something like this:

```
typedef std::tuple< *(bool())(obj), *(bool())(obj) > func_pair;
```

so the `func_pair` object store them, but no idea how to write it. Now, if it is possible I want, precisely, to store some methods of the object passed by parameter. Lets say that I have:

```
class Obj:
  public:
    ...
  private:
    bool func1();
    bool func2();
    ...
}
```

then the tuple would be `{func1, func2}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the syntax for function pointers wrong -- it should be:

```
typedef std::tuple< bool(*)(Obj *), bool(*)(Obj *) > func_pair;
```

However, then you have the problem that methods aren't functions so method pointers and function pointers are incompatible (you can't convert between them).  So you could instead use method pointers:

```
typedef std::tuple< bool(Obj::*)(), bool(Obj::*)() > func_pair;
```

which would allow creating a func_pair as

```
func_pair { &Obj::func1, &Obj::func2 }
```

Alternately, you could use `std::function` which is a flexible "callable" that can be bound to any function pointer or functor object with the appropriate `operator()` method:

```
typedef std::tuple< std::function<bool(Obj *)>, std::function<bool(Obj *)> > func_pair;
```

You can convert method pointers into functor objects with `std::bind`, but it is usually easier to just use lambdas which are just the right thing to begin with

```
func_pair { [](Obj *o) { o->func1(); }, [](Obj *o) { o->func2(); } }
```

Comment: many thanks, I have never heard of method pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Class member functions do not decay to simple function pointers, they are more complicated.  An easy, though it comes with some overhead, solution to use is to have a tuple of [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)s and then for member functions you can wrap the call of the function on an object in a lambda expression.  That would look like

```
Obj cat;
using func_pair = std::tuple<std::function<bool()>, std::function<bool()>>;
func_pair fp{[&](){ return cat.func1(); }, [&](){ return cat.func2(); }};
// or capture by value instead to get a copy in each function object
func_pair fp{[=](){ return cat.func1(); }, [=](){ return cat.func2(); }};
```